# Limit number of CPU cores in bare metal server

Tags: centos, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor, bare-metal

I was trying to benchmark application performance across bare metal and hypervisors. I have a 24-core server on which hyper-v is running. On the same machine, I have centos7 installed. I can set the number of cores a VM can get from hyper-v console, but how can I do the same for bare-metal case as well?

I'm aware of using nr_cpus or max_cpus parameters in grub or even hot unplugging the core via /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu/online [source](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2018/01/how-to-limit-cpu-count-or-disable-cpus/) but I'm facing a small problem there. Hyper-V doesn't allow hard-affinity for processors, and when I try to switch off certain cores in bare-metal manually, the performance in VM is better. I need a method in which the number of cores can be fixed but the id of those are allowed to change.

Comment: See if you can limit the number of cores in the system BIOS. I've had to do this in the past on some HPE DL 380 Gen 8 (or 9) servers to satisfy some database (TimesTen) licensing limitations - our architecture team only purchased licensing for 12 cores on a 20/24 core bare metal servers.

Comment: Tried masking the CPUs from BIOS and it worked as expected. Thanks

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer, so it can be accepted and voted on.

Answer (score 1):

On the bare metal CentOS 7 machine, you can use the `nr_cpus` kernel boot parameter. [From the docs:](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)

```
nr_cpus=        [SMP] Maximum number of processors that an SMP kernel
                could support.
```

Alternatively, you can use cgroups or the [`cpulimit`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/1/cpulimit/) tool for limiting the CPU time available to specific user-space programs.